# How can I use CSS to make my table scroll horizontally? (in addition to vertically)

Tags: css

I've got my `<tbody>` scrolling vertically with the `<thead>` staying put. Now I'd like to make the whole table scroll horizontally. The trouble is once I set a width on the containing `<div>`, it all breaks, likely because the `<td>`s are `display: inline-block`. Any suggestsions?

Here it is working, without a set width of the table:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
/*   width: 500px; */
}

table {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead,
tbody {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

th,
td {
  width: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>first_name</th>
        <th>last_name</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here it is when I set a width on the containing `<div>`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
}

table {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead,
tbody {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

th,
td {
  width: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>first_name</th>
        <th>last_name</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ralph</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
        <td>rwright0@indiatimes.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Walter</td>
        <td>Sullivan</td>
        <td>wsullivan1@photobucket.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For table, keep display:block and edit overflow to read like this:

```
table {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

to your table.